# C primary expressions - Is it primary expression or not?

Tags: c, sdl

I'm using this basic [sdl](/questions/tagged/sdl) program to learn print screen.

I get the following error when I run the application:

> error: expected primary expression before '=' token"

```
#include "SDL.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
#define window 
using namespace std; 
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640; 
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480; 
int main( int argc, char* args[] ) 
{
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface =NULL; 
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ) 
    { 
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n",SDL_GetError() ); 
    } 
    else 
    {  
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    } 
    if(window==NULL) 
    { 
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `window`? Can you perhaps please try  to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: sure. here it is
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define window
using namespace std;
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640; 
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
int main( int argc, char* args[] ) 
{
    
      SDL_Surface* screenSurface =NULL; 
      if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
       {
            printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n",SDL_GetError() );
            }
    else 
    { 
            window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
             }
      if(window==NULL)

Comment: Oh, and please *edit your question* to show the code. :)

Comment: But already now I can say that this looks suspect: `#define window`, define it as *what*?

Comment: dude.. m new here.. and really i dont know what u mean.. please explain.

Comment: yeah.. define it as it is.. window as a word as it is not a keyword or anything..

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor is simple, when it has a macro it replaces that macro *as is*.

For example if you have

```
#define window
```

then the preprocessor will replace all occurrences of the symbol `windows` with ***nothing***!

So for the statement

```
window = SDL_CreateWindow(...);
```

it will look like this after preprocessing

```
 = SDL_CreateWindow(...);
```

That's hardly valid code.

If you intend for `window` to be a variable, a pointer to `SDL_Window`, then you should define it as such:

```
SDL_Window *window;
```

and *remove* the preprocessor macro.

---

I agree that the terminology is slightly confusing here. You use the preprocessor to *define* macros, and then you can *define* variables, structures, functions etc. You can also *declare* variables, structures, functions etc.

The preprocessor is what it sounds like. It used to be a separate program that read a source file, did some *processing* on it (like macro replacement and include file inclusion) and then spat out a temporary file that the compiler then used. These days the preprocessor could be built into the compiler, and run at an early stage as part of the complete compilation process. Most compilers allow you to output the preprocessed source for you to look at, I suggest you try to do that with your code. Macros defined for the preprocessor are not in the source fed to the compiler, those lines are removed by the preprocessor.

Then comes the definition of variables etc. This is completely different from the definition of preprocessor macros. A variable definition tells the compilers "here is a variable with the name this-and-that, of some type, please allocate memory to store the variable".

A variable *declaration* is similar to a definition, but it only tells the compiler "there is a variable named this-and-that, of some specific type, and it exists somewhere".

Variables can be both declared and defined at the same time, example

```
void function(void)
{
    int a;  // Declares and defines the variable
    ...
}
```

Comment: dude.. I did exactly what u said.. now its showing "SDL_Window does not name a type SDL_Window*window"
what to do now.. :(

Comment: Find where it is defined and include appropriate header

Answer (score 0):

Modify your program this way:

```
#include "SDL.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
using namespace std;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640; 
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480; 
SDL_Window *window;
int main( int argc, char* args[] ) 
{
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface =NULL; 
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ) 
    { 
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n",SDL_GetError() ); 
    } 
    else 
    {  
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    } 
    if(window==NULL) 
    { 
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working.. now it's saying "SDL_Window does not name a type SDL_Window*window"....??!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
#define window
```

to

```
SDL_Window * window;
```